# Terraform type definition for multi-level map

Tags: terraform

I have the following local definition:

```
locals {
  dbservers = {
    managementDBserver = {
      storage    = 32768
      db_version = "12"
      databases = {
        name      = "mgmt"
        collation = "en_US.utf8"
        charset   = "utf8"
      }
    }
    reportingDBserver = {
      storage    = 32768
      db_version = "12"
      databases = {
        name      = "reports"
        collation = "en_US.utf8"
        charset   = "utf8"
      }
    }
    coreDBserver = {
      storage    = 32768
      db_version = "12"
      databases = {
        name      = "core"
        collation = "en_US.utf8"
        charset   = "utf8"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And I don't know how to specify the variable type definition when passed into a module because this fails ( database_servers = local.dbservers):

```
variable "database_servers" {
  type = map(object({
    storage    = number
    db_version = string
    databases = map(object({
      name      = string
      collation = string
      charset   = string
    }))
  }))
}
```

The error is: "managementDBserver": attribute "databases": element "name": object required.

When the definition was one level like this:

```
locals {
  databases = {
    management = {
      name      = "mgmt"
      collation = "en_US.utf8"
      charset   = "utf8"
    }
    reporting = {
      name      = "reports"
      collation = "en_US.utf8"
      charset   = "utf8"
    }
  }
}
```

The following was correct:

```
variable  "server_databases" {
    type = map(object({
      name      = string
      collation = string
      charset   = string
    }))
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested `databases` attribute appears to be an `object` type, and not a `map(object)`:

```
type = map(object({
  storage    = number
  db_version = string
  databases = object({
    name      = string
    collation = string
    charset   = string
  })
}))
```

However the plural "databases" does imply multiple are possible in which case `list(object)` would be necessary. Alternatively the nested `name` attribute could be used as the key of a `map(object)` if there are multiple. However, this is for theoretical use cases, and the type above is the literal answer for the question as written.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Matt, I saw what I was missing. The correct local definition is:

```
locals {
  dbservers = {
    managementdbserver = {
      storage    = 32768
      db_version = "12"
      databases = {
        db1 = {
          name      = "mgmt"
          collation = "en_US.utf8"
          charset   = "utf8"
        }
      }
    }
    reportingdbserver = {
      storage    = 32768
      db_version = "12"
      databases = {
        db1 = {
          name      = "mgmt"
          collation = "en_US.utf8"
          charset   = "utf8"
        }
      }
    }
    coredbserver = {
      storage    = 32768
      db_version = "12"
      databases = {
        db1 = {
          name      = "mgmt"
          collation = "en_US.utf8"
          charset   = "utf8"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Especially since I had the intention to have more than one database per server.